# How to prepend a consecutive sequence number to every paragraph using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

In my UI, I have a button and some paragraphs. The requirement is to prepend consecutive sequence numbers to every paragraph on clicking of the button.

I tried it this way. But it did not work.

```
var count=0;
$("#buttonGparano").click(function(){
jQuery.each($("#col2 p").not(".append").prepend(++count));
});
});
```

On 1st click, it is prepending '1' to every paragraph, then on 2nd click, it is prepending '2' and so on.
I want that when I click once, the 1st para should have sequence no. 1, 2nd paragraph should have sequence no. 2 and so on.

The paragraphs are written like this:

```
<div id="col2">
<p class="firstparagraph">
Lorem ipsum sit amet, consecte elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod <em>tincidunt</em> ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat </p>
<p class="secondparagraph">
Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse <strong>molestie</strong> consequat, vel illum eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio</p>
</div>
```

My code should first find how many paragraphs are there totally, and assign them consecutive value. I mean to say the code should work for any number of paragraphs.
Please suggest something if anyone has any idea.

Comment: dont use same id for multiple elements and please show some HTML

Comment: Each paragraph has a separate class and are enclosed in a common div id.

Comment: @ AmmarCSE, Please find above the HTML Code of the paragraphs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to store your own counter, use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate your elements and use the built-in index:

Runnable snippet below:

```js
$("#buttonGparano").one('click', function(){
  $("#col2 p").each(function(index) {
    $(this).prepend(index + 1);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="buttonGparano" value="Click" />
<div id="col2">
  <p>
  </p>
  <p>
  </p>
  <p>
  </p>
  <p>
  </p>
  <p>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var click = 0;
$('button').click(function () {
    $('p').eq(click).prepend($('p').eq(click).index('p')+1);
    click++;
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/0g1mmssn/)**

```
$('button').click(function () {
    $('p').each(function (i) {
        $(this).prepend(i+1);
    })
    $(this).off('click')
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/qj8vgzns/2)**

Comment: The sequence numbers are getting prepended to each para on clicking the button one by one. I want the sequence numbers to be prepended to all paragraphs  together on single click

Answer (score 1):

To set numbers on all paragraphs at same time use this:

```
var count=0;
$("#buttonGparano").click(function(){
    $("p").each(function(i, item){
        $(item).prepend(++count);
    });
});
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/e36vjpn7/

Comment: You've already got the variable `i`, no need to use a separate `count` variable

Comment: I agree, I upvote you for that. Yours is the correct answer :)

Comment: Yours is correct too, and I only beat you by a few seconds, +1.